# wherei need to create /.config/winapps/winapps.conf

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization, configuration, rdp

Step 3: Creating your WinApps configuration file

You will need to create a ~/.config/winapps/winapps.conf configuration file with the following information in it:

RDP_USER="MyWindowsUser"
RDP_PASS="MyWindowsPassword"
#RDP_DOMAIN="MYDOMAIN"
#RDP_IP="192.168.123.111"
#RDP_SCALE=100
#RDP_FLAGS=""
#MULTIMON="true"
#DEBUG="true"

The username and password should be a full user account and password, such as the one created when setting up Windows or a domain user. It cannot be a user/PIN combination as those are not valid for RDP access.

Options:

```
When using a pre-existing non-KVM RDP server, you can use the RDP_IP to specify it's location
If you are running a VM in KVM with NAT enabled, leave RDP_IP commented out and WinApps will auto-detect the right local IP
For domain users, you can uncomment and change RDP_DOMAIN
On high-resolution (UHD) displays, you can set RDP_SCALE to the scale you would like [100|140|160|180]
To add flags to the FreeRDP call, such as /audio-mode:1 to pass in a mic, use the RDP_FLAGS configuration option
For multi-monitor setups, you can try enabling MULTIMON, however if you get a black screen (FreeRDP bug) you will need to revert back
If you enable DEBUG, a log will be created on each application start in ~/.local/share/winapps/winapps.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> where i need to create /.config/winapps/winapps.conf

You are missing a vital character: the `~`.

> Step 3: Creating your WinApps configuration file
>
> You will need to create a `~/.config/winapps/winapps.conf` configuration file with the following information in it:

The `~` automatically translates to your users home directory (so is equal to `/home/$USER/`). We use a `~` because we all have different user names and this makes it usable for all.